# python: modify level of logs from a module

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

### TLDR

if a module uses

```
log.error("something happened")
```

we would like to see these logs, but as warnings, so that the net effect for us would be the same as if that module had used

```
log.warning("something happened")
```

### More details

We use the [aiokafka module which logs errors](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiokafka/blob/master/aiokafka/consumer/fetcher.py#L661) when the connection with confluent.cloud has trouble. However these are transient problems and after a while connection is re-established, so we would have preferred these logs to be **warning** instead of **error**, yet we don't want to lose those logs.

Is there a way to modify these log records "on the fly", to change their log level? I know I could

```
logger = logging.getLogger("aiokafka")
logger.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```

but then all logs would get lost.

Comment: Could you overwrite the error function to the warning function, i.e. `logging.getLogger("aiokafka").error = logging.getLogger("aiokafka").warning`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can attach a filter function to the logger which downgrades the level. Here'a a working example you can use to build from:

```
import logging

def downgrade_filter(record):
    if record.levelno == logging.ERROR:
        record.levelno = logging.WARNING
        record.levelname = logging.getLevelName(logging.WARNING)
    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(levelname)-8s|%(name)-8s|%(message)s')
    logger = logging.getLogger('aiokafka')
    logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    logger.addFilter(downgrade_filter)
    logger.debug('This should not appear')
    logger.info('This should not appear')
    logger.warning('This should appear as a warning')
    logger.error('This should appear as a warning, though logged as an error')
    logger.critical('This should appear as a critical error')
```

When run, it should print

```
WARNING |aiokafka|This should appear as a warning
WARNING |aiokafka|This should appear as a warning, though logged as an error
CRITICAL|aiokafka|This should appear as a critical error
```

(This is on a recent version of Python 3.x)

Comment: This will turn every ERROR to WARNING - right? So we better look inside the log record attributes and find the attributes that will "filter" only messages we want to modify.

Comment: Not *every* ERROR, just the ones logged to that logger. One can of course tweak the filter function to do whatever is needed, but that's the basic approach.

Comment: Agreed - I voted up.